# Select Individual XML Bound Items in TreeView

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I am trying to learn how to bind the following simple XML file to a WPF `TreeView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Profiles>

  <Customer>
    <Name>Customer1</Name>    
    <Profile>
      <Version>1.0</Version>
      <DisplayText>DisplayText1</DisplayText>
    </Profile>
    <Profile>
      <Version>1.0</Version>
      <DisplayText>DisplayText2</DisplayText>
    </Profile>
  </Customer>

  <Customer>
    <Name>Customer2</Name>    
    <Profile>
      <Version>1.0</Version>
      <DisplayText>DisplayText3</DisplayText>
    </Profile>    
  </Customer>

</Profiles>
```

Here is my XAML code of the attempt:

```
 <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="auto" Name="treeView1" Width="217"
           SelectedItemChanged="UIProfileTreeViewSelectedItemChanged"
           ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <TreeView.DataContext>
         <XmlDataProvider Source="Profiles.xml" XPath="/Profiles/Customer"/>
     </TreeView.DataContext>
     <TreeView.Resources>
         <DataTemplate DataType="Customer">
             <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding XPath=Name}"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Profile}"/>
         </DataTemplate>                
         <DataTemplate DataType="Profile">
             <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding XPath=DisplayText}" />
         </DataTemplate>                
     </TreeView.Resources> 
 </TreeView>
```

However the results prevent me from selecting individual profiles under a customer in the `TreeView`, if I click one profile the whole group gets highlighted like so:

[alt text http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/4484/sberr.png](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/4484/sberr.png)

I clearly have a conceptual error with how databound items work. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with the xaml below.

There were two basic issues I ran into with your code:

1. Both levels of your treeview were using "DataTemplate" instead of the "outer" one being defined as a "HierarchicalDataTemplate" -- so you had to put the ItemsSource on the TreeViewItem, which appears to have caused the "selection as a group" issue
2. I was having trouble getting selection to work at all using TreeViewItems, but after converting the DataTemplates to show a Label (you could display any sort of simple or complex set of controls in here), it worked perfectly.  WPF automatically inserts "TreeViewItem" controls to wrap whatever you bind into a TreeView, so you don't need to do it explicitly.

   ```
       <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="auto" Name="treeView1" Width="217" SelectedItemChanged="UIProfileTreeViewSelectedItemChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
         <TreeView.DataContext>
           <XmlDataProvider Source="Profiles.xml" XPath="/Profiles/Customer"/>
         </TreeView.DataContext>
         <TreeView.Resources>
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Customer" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Profile}">
               <Label Content="{Binding XPath=Name}" />
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
           <DataTemplate DataType="Profile">
               <Label Content="{Binding XPath=DisplayText}" />
           </DataTemplate>
         </TreeView.Resources>
       </TreeView>
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, GS. It looks like HierarchicalDataTemplate was the main thing I was missing! Cheers